# Why is the namespace being added to a child node during XML serialization?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have a class decorated for XML serialization like so:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "XXX", Namespace = "http://www.example.com/Schemas/xxx/2011/11")]
public class Xxx<T> where T: Shipment
{
    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string Version = "1.1";

    public T Shipment { get; set; }

    public Xxx(string dataTargetType)
    {
        Shipment = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        Shipment.DataContext = new DataContext
        {
            DataTargetCollection = new DataTargetCollection
            {
                DataTarget = new DataTarget
                {
                    Type = dataTargetType
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

[XmlType("Shipment")]
public class Shipment
{
    public DataContext DataContext { get; set; }
}
```

When serialized it is outputting the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XXX xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Shipment xmlns="http://www.example.com/Schemas/xxx/2011/11">
        <DataContext>
            <DataTargetCollection>
                <DataTarget>
                    <Type>WarehouseOrder</Type>
                </DataTarget>
            </DataTargetCollection>
        </DataContext>
    </Shipment>
</XXX>
```

Why is the xmlns namespace attribute being added to the `Shipment` node rather than the root `XXX` node?

Example of it in use being inherited and serialized: (contrived example while working out serialization issues)

```
public class XxxVariation: Xxx<Shipment>
{
    public const string DataTargetType = "Something";

    public XxxVariation() : base(DataTargetType) {}
}

public async Task<string> CreateXxxVariationAsync(string todo)
{
    var request = new XxxVariation();

    string xmlRequest = SerializeRequest(request);
    return await PostRequestAsync(xmlRequest);
}

private static string SerializeRequest<T>(T request)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.Serialize(XmlWriter.Create(stream), request);

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return xml;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can we see the code you're using to serialize here? what object *are* you serializing, because `Xxx<T>` doesn't have a public parameterless constructor, so I don't think it is *that*

Comment: @MarcGravell I've added some code to show how I'm serializing and inherited class. The parameterless constructor made no difference, probably because the class that inherited from it has a parameterless constructor already.

Comment: edit is pretty close to my guesswork, then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that `Xxx<T>` doesn't have a public parameterless constructor, I *suspect* what you actually have is something like:

```cs
public class FooXxx : Xxx<Foo> {
    public FooXxx() : base("abc") { }
}
```

and that you are serializing the `FooXxx` instance, and using `typeof(FooXxx)` when creating the `XmlSerializer`. That's... OK I guess, and in theory `XmlRootAttribute` is inheritable, but I suspect that the attribute inspection code is explicitly using the "only on the declared type, not inherited" option when checking for attributes. Because of this, it seems that you need to add the attribute *again* on `FooXxx`:

```cs
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "XXX", Namespace = "http://www.example.com/Schemas/xxx/2011/11")]
public class FooXxx : Xxx<Foo> {
    public FooXxx() : base("abc") { }
}
```

Note: I've had to infer a lot here; if this doesn't help, please post the *actual code you're using to serialize*, including your `XmlSerializer` initialization, and showing the creation of the object you pass into the serializer.

Comment: yes, very impressive inferring you did there! Much appreciated for your help :) Was a late night coding session so forgot to say thanks.